# Can we use Ampscript in Html email body to collect multiple click details?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dynamic

We have set of journey flow which has decision split for click on all links based on that activity another email will be deployed. But we have to add dynamic field values after click decision split based on click counts. I have tried with Update contact but which can be used only static value update for all contacts.

Can we add ampscript to get in email body or is there anyway to update?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear - do you want to base a decision split on multiple links being clicked?

Answer (score 0):

So, if they click a link (email A) then the journey splits (email B and email C)? You want email B and email C to produce different content blocks? If that's the case, you could add columns to the data extension that are true/false. Then, if value is true show a content block. I could be wrong, but I don't believe there is a different way for AMPScript to work from clicks.